# Рисование .gif анимации на PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Привет всем.Возникла задача реализовать рисование .gif анимации на PictureBox.В PictureBox есть уже изображение,нужно чтобы при нажатии появлялась gif анимации.Во так только с анимацией: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине использую

```
Graphics gr = Picturebox1.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawImage(GshopImagesLinker.Properties.Resources._16, X_index, Y_index+128, 128, 6);
```

Comment: Я смотрел эту темы,и еще многие на этом и других форумах.Некоторые кода не работают,некоторые делают что то другое.

Comment: Так как вы вручную отрисовываете изображения, то используйте класс [ImageAnimator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imageanimator(v=vs.110).aspx). Пример смотрите, например, [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate(v=vs.110).aspx). Но гораздо проще использовать отдельный `PictureBox` на каждое изображение.

Comment: ImageAnimator пробовал,забыл указать в первом посте.На счет второго варианта:предлагаете создать 1500 picturebox?Ибо большое изображение делится почти на 1500 изображений размером 128х128

Comment: Не надо приписывать мне свои мысли. Я предлагаю столько пикчабоксов с анимациями, сколько их должно быть видно в данный момент.

Comment: Я ничего не предлагал.Вы имеете в виду создать отдельный picturebox,при перемещении перемещать его по нужным координатам и отображать?

Comment: Пишите ник пользователя со значком @ перед ним, чтобы он получал извещение о сообщении ему. Я бы не узнал, что вы мне что-то написали, если бы не зашёл непосредственно в тему.

Comment: Примерно так. Только учтите, что формат gif всегда плохо поддерживался в Windows. Во времена .net 2.0 некоторые гифки приводили к исключениям в недрах GDI+. С тех пор, насколько я знаю, что-то чинилось, но кто знает... Поэтому используйте `PictureBox` с анимированными gif на свой страх и риск. Тщательно тестируйте их, если создаёте сами. Как вариант, используйте компоненты других производителей, или `WebBrowser` (он гарантированно работает с gif, но уж очень тяжеловесен).